# How to caulk uneven gap in corner of kitchen backsplash?

Tags: caulk

We have tiled the backsplash in our kitchen. The grouting is done and we are caulking. We are having problems caulking the corners where the two walls meet. (The vertical line) The tiles are uneven and we are getting a wobbly caulk line. Any ideas on how to make this look like a straight line? Th[image]anks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think the trouble is with your tooling method. It's wobbly. :)

Either trim your tube better to act as a forming tool itself, or make a tool out of cardboard or plastic, or purchase one of those found at hardware stores to achieve more consistency.

You could also mask the lines with tape, caulk, and remove the tape. This may leave raised edges, though.